# Is checking developer mode reliable enough to counter fake GPS?

Tags: android, location, android-gps

I'm working on an Android app, which are used by salesperson who visit shops/stores based on agreed plan. Each time the person arrives at the store, he will press a button on the app, which send his current location to the server.

We don't want lazy salesperson using fakegps apps. Assuming the phone is not-rooted, is checking if developer mode is enabled sufficient? For the sake of curiosity, I downloaded top 5 "fake GPS" apps on Playstore, and all of them require mock location to be enabled. Just wonder if there's a way to bypass the limitation (obviously without rooting the phone).

Most of the salesperson use Android 11 and 12. A few use 13.